# Should I inherit from a Model when creating a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to create a ViewModel, which is almost identical to the underlying Model, but with 2 added attributes. As an example, I have a Model named `Person` and the ViewModel would then look like:

```
public class PersonVM : Person
{
   public string Subscription {get; set;}
   public int? OtherAttribute {get; set;}
}
```

Is this the most optimal scenario or should I not inherit, but include it in the class like this?

```
public class PersonVM
{
   public Person Person {get; set;}
   public string Subscription {get; set;}
   public int? OtherAttribute {get; set;}
}
```

The advantage of inheritance would be maintainability and ease of coding. When calling an attribute in the first scenario would be direct e.g. `PersonVM.LastName`, while in the second scenario the same call would be longer and potentially confusing: `PersonVM.Person.LastName`. What should be the considerations when choosing between these alternatives?

Comment: By "model" I assume you mean `Person` is an Entity Framework entity? You don't expose those.

Comment: Normally you've have complete separation between the VM classes and the database model classes, with no inheritance etc between them. This gives you flexibility in terms of structure, which fields are in which view models, and removes any potential issues with things like serialisation which you can sometimes get with EF models (e.g. due to circular references). Many developers use tools like AutoMapper to then handle the tedious work of translating a VM object into the relevant model objects, and back again.

Comment: If Person and PersonVM are in the same layer in your application, then you can use inheritance flow. However, if they belong to a different layer, like one in MVC view model other in the business layer, you should create different models and maybe use automapper to map fields.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. I've learned there is a preference to separate Model and ViewModel. I will most certainly investigate AutoMapper.

Comment: It's up to you. You will probably find that best practice is to have separation. For example, if there's a case where you change some property in model, this change can be handled in mapper without changing UI stuff and similar use cases. I personally used the second example in the past sometimes.